# apex submmit page to another sever

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX page that collects data via an input form and need submit all values to another server http://pro.anotherserver.com/Read/date

My form page look like this:
[image: Form data entry]

the properties of the "send" button have this values.

[image]

My question is: Where I can change the URL target of the form?

My server is Oracle 11G, Apex 5.1.4

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Normally the target of an APEX page must be the server that generated the page. The exception would be integration with a 3rd party server (e.g. for accepting credit card payments via a payment gateway) - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: you are right, I'm try to integrate with service payments. Provider specifaction  requiere send data via post method.

Comment: Ok. I've done that once before, I'll have to dig into my code to remember the tricks I had to do to allow the web page to post to a different server, then do a second post back to APEX.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see images at the moment; nonetheless, from what you've described, I'd say that you got it wrong.

In Apex, a workspace (that contains your application) is mapped to one (or more) database users (schemas). By default, when you create a (form) page, it is based on a table that is located in that user's schema, in that very database.

You'd want to store data elsewhere, i.e. in another database. It is not URL that you should change, but *target* table.

As another database comes into the game, you should create a **database link** from your database (user, schema) to another database (search for `CREATE DATABASE LINK` command). Once you do that and verify that it works, create a **synonym** for the target table (search for `CREATE SYNONYM`). You should be able to manipulate its data (try DML from current user's connection).

Now, Apex: when creating a form page, you can  select a table or a view that belongs to you. I'm not sure whether you can see synonyms as well (I *think* not). It means that you should *fool* Apex; here's how:

- before creating a synonym, create a *table* in your own schema
- create Apex form page, based on that table
- once you make it work, drop the table and create a synonym - it *must* have the same name as previously dropped table
- run the page; submitted data should now reside in a remote database

Good luck!